# API Gateway pass array of parameters in querystring

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, parameters, query-string, aws-api-gateway

I have some issues with passing array of parameters to query string for GET method, for example, `/resource&item=1&item=2&item=3`.

I have tried to pass parameters separated by commas and by &, it doesn`t work. How to configure API Gateway to do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I tried answering a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191809/1410035

Answer (score 2):

Your example was using an ampersand (&) instead of a question mark (?) for separating the query string parameter from the path. I'm assuming that's just a typo.

Try passing the array using json syntax like

`/resource?item=['1','2','3']`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this way :

```
/resource&item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3
```

The way you used would erase the first data by the last data in the url.

Comment: The same problem, finally I got the last data

Comment: You shouldn't have to configure anything to make this work. This is standard HTTP request format. How are you fetching the datas ?

Comment: Their Known Issues https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html states that you can't do this: `Duplicated headers are not supported.`

Comment: `Duplicate query string parameters are not supported.` Which is the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

What we are doing in our company is to pass data separated by `,`. On Backend we explode the parameter and make it array again. I am not sure if there is more better way to do it or not. Let me know if you find any.

like `?items=1,2,3,4`

And we get explode items with , through extra code

and get result as `[1,2,3,4]`